# Why document is not deleting in the mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

The problem that occurs is the user is not getting removed from the document in the database. The user is named mention.

This is the ingroups schema that im using

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    User:String,
    GroupName:String,
    TotalAmountDonated:Number,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("InGroup", groupSchema, 'InGroups')
```

**This is where the mention variable comes from**

```
 .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
             subcommand
            .setName('kick')
            .setDescription('Kick an unfortunate group member')
            .addUserOption(option =>
              option
            .setName('groupmember')
            .setDescription('Group member you would like to kick')
            .setRequired(true))),
```

These are the if statements and for some reason the findOneAndDelete line is not working

```
const mention = interaction.options.getUser('groupmember');
const data1 = await ingroups.findOne({ User: mention.id });
if (data1 !== null) {
  if (data1.GroupName !== user.GroupName) {
    return await interaction.reply(
      'The person you are attempting to kick is not in your group.'
    );
  }
  await ingroups.findOneAndDelete({ User: mention.id });
  return await interaction.reply(
    `<@${mention.id}> has been successfully kicked from the group`
  );
} else {
  return await interaction.reply(
    'The user you are trying to kick is not in a group!'
  );
}
```

Comment: You can also try to use `findOneAndRemove`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already defined the group you want to delete.

Try:
await data1.delete();